# Wildfly-Swarm : Class not in Classpath in CDI wildfly-swarm microservice

Tags: java, cdi, wildfly-10, wildfly-swarm

I am building multiple microservices with wildfly-swarm. I have one microservice that works correctly and one that fails while trying to start the CDI-Container because the class com.google.common.cache.Cache is not present in the Classpath but is referenced from an ApplicationScoped Bean. This is the stacktrace i get:

```
WELD-001474: Class [...].core.framework.timeseries.cache.TimeseriesDataCache is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: com.google.common.cache.Cache from [Module \"deployment.43ef34ae-45a8-4468-aa7d-40d75c0f0a79.war:main\" from Service Module Loader].
```

The strange thing is that both microservices use this class from the same maven dependency, but the other service works like intended. The main difference is, that the failing microservice uses Ribbon (via the swarm-dependency) and this brings a second Guava-Dependency (version 14.0.1). Hence i tried to exclude the guava-dependency from Ribbon (coming from the netflix-guava module) in any way (by excluding the guava dependency directly on the main Ribbon artifact and by excluding the netflix-guava dependency from the main Ribbon aratifact and then adding the dependency for netflix-guava myself and excluding it there).
I was partly successful by manually excluding the guava artifact for version 14.0.1 in my main-class but that caused other issues and in my opinion would not be a viable option (since this behaviour could lead to us having to manually exclude any artifact that is shipped with some dependency if it causes problem.
So my question would be: is there any way to work around this behaviour? Or a solution i did not get from the swarm documentation? I am really lost right now and any help/idea is greatly appreciated. Just in case here is the code that builds my deployment as i would like it to work (without manually adding the neccessary artifacts to exclude unwanted ones):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Swarm container = new Swarm(args);
    final String offset = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;
    container = container.socketBindingGroup(new SocketBindingGroup("default-sockets","public","${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:" +
            offset != null ? offset : "0" +
            "}"));
    container
            .fraction(new JAXRSFraction())
            .fraction(new CDIFraction())
            .fraction(new LoggingFraction());

    JAXRSArchive jaxrsArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(JAXRSArchive.class);
    jaxrsArchive.addAsResource(new ClassLoaderAsset("META-INF/beans.xml", FormulaDeployment.class.getClassLoader()), "classes/META-INF/beans.xml");
    jaxrsArchive.addAllDependencies();
    jaxrsArchive.addAsLibrary(container.createDefaultDeployment());
    jaxrsArchive.as(RibbonArchive.class).advertise();

    container.start().deploy(jaxrsArchive);

}
```